# Custom Spinner too thin

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I'm creating a custom layout for my Spinner, whose code is this:

```
 <!-- spinner_item.xml -->
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:width="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"/>
```

and used as follows: `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item,list);`

And this is the result:

[image]

But each element is too thin, so I used a `padding-top` but with poor results:

[image]

And when I select one of them, it doesn't appear in the box (I think it's because it's too wide). Is there a way to acomplish that? Thank you.

Comment: Could you describe the desired result in more detail? What do you want the spinner to look like and which box are you referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used padding instead of margin

```
 <!-- spinner_item.xml -->
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
     android:padding="10dp"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, I used this method and it's how I'd like it, but when I select an item, it does not appear in the Spinner's box, do you know why?